# If $I^m=(a)^m$, for $I$ and $(a)$ ideals in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_L$ of a number field, can I deduce that $I=(a)$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I think that what I ask must be true. I would need such lemma to finish the proof that for every ideal $I$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ there exists a field extension $L$ of $K$ such that $I$ is a principal ideal in $\mathcal{O}_L$.

My proof goes like the first answer to this question: [Every ideal of an algebraic number field can be principal in a suitable finite extension field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241348/every-ideal-of-an-algebraic-number-field-can-be-principal-in-a-suitable-finite-e)

However, as I have not yet been introduced to fractional ideals, I do not see why, perhaps trivially, $I^m=J^m$ implies $I=J$, where $I$ and $J$ are both fractional ideals. 
But I have seen a proof of unique factorization into prime ideals for the ring of integers of a number field (I know that unique factorization into prime ideals holds for any Dedekind domain, despite not having yet learned the proof of this).

Can one prove what I ask in the question without needing fractional ideals? Or, if they are handy for this purpose, could you explain which properties of fractional ideals are used to deduce that $I^m=(a)^m$ implies $I=(a)$, for ideals in  $\mathcal{O}_L$  ?

Comment: As you say, any ideal in $\mathcal{O}_{L}$ admits a unique factorization into a product of prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_{L}$. With that in mind, suppose you had the prove the analogous statement that two integers $a, b$ which satisfy $a^{m} = b^{m}$ for some $m \geqslant 1$ must be equal (up to sign). How could you prove this statement using unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$? Could you adapt your proof to the setting you're interested in?

Comment: Yes, I can adapt the proof – I now see that my question was easy. Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad I could help!